# Samsung S2 reads out message aloud

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-2, settings

Some one has changed my phone settings, so when I recieve an SMS from any number the message is read out loudly.

Can someone tell me how to disable this?

My driving mode is turned off too.